# Calculating Mahalanobis distance with C#

Tags: c#, statistics, distance, covariance

I'm trying to calculate the mahalanobis distance with c#. I can't find any real good examples online and I'm new to C#. I am especially having trouble getting the covariance matrix to run right. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

namespace MahalanobisDistance
 {
   class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        DenseVector vector1 = new DenseVector(4);
        DenseVector vector2 = new DenseVector(4);
        DenseMatrix matrix1 = new DenseMatrix(vector1.Count/2);

        vector1[0] = 1;
        vector1[1] = 2;
        vector1[2] = 3;
        vector1[3] = 4;

        vector2[0] = 2;
        vector2[1] = 12;
        vector2[2] = 14;
        vector2[3] = 18;

        matrix1 = p.twoPassCovariance(vector1, vector2);
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < matrix1.ColumnCount; k++)
            {

                Console.Write(matrix1[k, i] + " ");
            }
            //Mahalanobis2(v1, v2, covariance);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }

    public DenseMatrix twoPassCovariance(DenseVector data1, DenseVector data2)
    {
        int n = data1.Count;

        double mean1 = data1.Average();
        double mean2 = data2.Average();

        DenseMatrix covariance = new DenseMatrix(data1.Count);
        double x;

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                double a = data1[i] - mean1;
                double b = data2[k] - mean2;
                x = a*b;
                covariance[i, k] = x;
            }
        }

        covariance.Multiply(1/n);
        return covariance;
    }

}}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question or are you looking for a code review?

Comment: Your vectors are really very small. Have you actually stepped through the code that creates the covariance matrix line by line in the debugger to see where the problem lies?

Answer (score 2):

In the `i` loop in the `twoPassCovariance` method, I believe you should loop to `i < n` rather than `i < 2`.