# Mahalanobis distance in math.net

Tags: c#, math, math.net

I am new to math.net library. I need to find mahalanobis distance but I am not able to find any specific function in the description

Is there any function available in math.net for Mahalanobis distance computation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no available a function for calculating Mahalanobis distance. Maybe, this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037697/calculating-mahalanobis-distance-with-c-sharp

Comment: @sinanakyazici, thank you. Do you know are there any functions for following terms in math.net

1. nonlinear minimization
2. varinace-covariance matrix (I know there is covariance function but is for vector only, I need for a matrix)
3. quantile function for normal distribution specifically

Comment: You will need to look for BFGS algorithm for 1. I believe they have added this in the latest release. 2. This can be calculated easily from the tools provided by MathNET. 3. See 2.

Comment: OpenCV has a Mahalanobis function